# How to show facebook photo gallery in my app?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.0

Is there a way for me to pull Facebook photo album and display it in my app ? I mean **with the UI Interface to select the photo**, not only to retrieve the url of the photos (via graph api I guess) and later build our-self the ui interface (ie: the gallery) to let the user select the photo.

Is their something like this in the facebook SDK for android/ios ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use to Graph API in Facebook SDK

```
/* make the API call */
new GraphRequest(
    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
    "/{album-id}/photos",
    null,
    HttpMethod.GET,
    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
            /* handle the result */
        }
    }
).executeAsync();
```

[Facebook Graph API alum photos](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.9/album/photos)

Add the compile dependency with the latest version of the Facebook SDK in the build.gradle file:

```
dependencies { 
  compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
}
```

[facebook getting started](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/)

Add Facebook App ID

Then add your Facebook App ID to your project's strings file and update your Android manifest:

1. Open your strings.xml file. Example path: /app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml.
2. Add a new string with the name facebook_app_id and value as your Facebook App ID
3. Open AndroidManifest.xml
4. Add a uses-permission element to the manifest:

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android

please move to Basic guide for Android site
You can download sdk

Comment: @loki https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/
you can build in gradle or download sdk file

Comment: you don't understand, i want the UI interface ! i know perfectly how to use the sdk, i want just the UI interface ... you know the windows where the user can choose the picture ...